# Question on derivation of solution for heat equation

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

[image]

The above is taken from Evans book. I can not understand how this scaling indicates that the $\frac{r^2}{t}\;\;$ is invariant. I would appreciate if somebody could explain to me this part with more details. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I thought also to do this: I chose $λ^2 t\;=\; 1$ and so I found $λ$ to be equal $\frac{1}{\sqrt t}$. Then by substitution to $u$ I concluded $u(λx,λ^2 t)=u(\frac{x}{\sqrt t} ,1)=v(\frac{x}{\sqrt t})$ Does this somehow imply that $v(\frac{{\vert x \vert}^2}{ t})$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $u(x,t)$ is a solution of

$$u_t = \Delta u$$

then $w(x,t) = u(\lambda x, \lambda^2 t)$ also solves the heat equation:

$$w_t(x,t) = \lambda^2 u_t(\lambda x, \lambda^2 t) = \lambda^2 \Delta u(\lambda x, \lambda^2 t) = \Delta w(x,t).$$

This scaling $x\to \lambda x$, $t\to \lambda^2 t$ is thus an invariance of the heat equation.  In other words this is a symmetry of the PDE.  Then one observes that by taking $y=\lambda x$ and $s = \lambda^2 t$ we have $\frac{|y|^2}{t} = \frac{|x|^2}{t}$ is independent of $\lambda$. This independence from $\lambda$ is important because the variable $\xi = \frac{|x|^2}{t}$ takes advantage of the symmetry property of the heat equation. In fact, $\frac{r^2}{t}$ is not an invariant as you ask; rather the $\lambda$-independence leads us to conjecture a solution of the heat equation of the form $v(\xi)=v\left(\frac{|x|^2}{t}\right).$

I admit that this is not the most satisfying answer as it still requires some divine inspiration! Perhaps someone has a more rigorous way to "guess" $v(\xi)$...

Comment: First of all thank you for your quick response! I thought also to do this: I chose $λ^2 t\;=\; 1\;$ and so I found $λ\;$ to be equal $\frac{1}{\sqrt t}\;$ . Then by substitution to $u$ I concluded $u(λx,λ^2 t)=u(\frac{x}{\sqrt t} ,1)=v(\frac{x}{\sqrt t})$ Does this somehow imply that $v=(\frac{\vert x \vert}{ t})$ ? However thanks again for your help

Comment: One thing that you are missing in your derivation is the radial symmetry.  Note that by taking $v= v(r)$ where $r= |x|^2/t$, we have reduced the PDE to an ODE (in $r$).  From your derivation $v$ is still a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so we haven't gained anything.  I think an important point is to establish a solvable ODE.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I was just wondering if I could somehow by the above derivation conclude that finally $v=v(\frac{{\vert x \vert}^2}{t})$. If there 's a "trick" or something..

Comment: I see.  Off the top of my head I do not see anything in particular I'm afraid, but perhaps there is a way to get the desired conclusion.

Comment: Even if this is an old question, I hope that this provides some useful insight for people in the future: We explicitly want to find a self-similar solution, i.e., a solution u satisyfying $$u(x,t) = \lambda^\alpha  u(\lambda^\beta x, \lambda t).$$
We can now „remove“ one argument in u by choosing, for such a $u$, $\lambda=t^{-1}$. Insertion into $$ u(x,t)=  \lambda^\alpha  u(\lambda^\beta x, \lambda t)$$ gives $$u(x,t)= 1/t^\alpha u(x/t^\beta, 1).$$ Now simply replace $u(x/t^\beta,1)$ with $v(x/t^\beta)$ and you are done. This is motivated by the invariance of the h.eq. by parabolic scaling.